# What is this vintage font?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif, vintage

Help me I dont know what this font is. I have tried using What the font and other programs. I believe its a older PC or Windows font but not sure. Can't find it.
DM[image: FONT]

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Peignot Bold to me!

[image: Peignot Bold]

Comment: Right on. It predates the PC (as we know it) by some 50 years. I am pretty sure it was never included in any version of Windows.